# Mobile Safari: store camera uploads in photo album

Tags: ios, html, safari

I am working on a site that allows users to upload photos from their iPad. This works well, but the photos are not stored locally on the iPad in the Photos application. Is there a way for photos made directly from Safari to be stored there or is this not possible?